# Making a Video using only text, correct way to do this?

Tags: workflow, video, text-object

I'm Trying to make a video using just Text, but I don't know the best way to do this.
I just want some kind of simple 2D edition also on my computer blenders take too long to render 3D scenes, what would be the best way to do this?

- I have to create scenes for each group of text I want to show?
- Or maybe it's better to just use images with text?
- Or just use one Scene and use keyframes to get text inside and out of a the scene?

Comment: Could you please provide some reference of the effect you are trying to achieve? Right now your question is rather vague.

Comment: For example, a video where you explain something using just text and sounds.

Comment: So what is your issue exactly?

Comment: I don't really know how to do it. I can do it creating scenes and placing text there, but it seems to take so long to edit and render. hoping that somebody with some experiencie could lead me to a best way to do it.

Comment: have you tried using layers?

Comment: yes, is just that using scenes and text-objects seems to be too complicated for what I want to achieve.

Comment: Not scenes, layers. There is a huge difference

Comment: then. Yes, is just that using scenes, layers and text-objects seems to be too complicated for what I want to achieve.

Comment: OK, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: "You just can do it that way" could also be an answer to my question. Thanks for your time NoviceInDisguise :)

Comment: Do you have an example of the type of result you are trying to copy? A video or something? I need a better idea of exactly what you need to accomplish to make sure I can write a relevant answer, whether that is no there isn't, or this is how you can do it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg0TXNXgz-w // something like this, but without the effects and moving images, just text, that appears and move around.

Comment: I'd use text objects and [opengl rendering](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/opengl.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Blender 2.76 (or more exactly since the [Gooseberry Branch](https://gooseberry.blender.org/gooseberry-in-blender-master/)) there is a new [Text Effect](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/Sequencer#Text_Effect) strip that you can add in the VSE which should help you do what you want to. There are already enough [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-qMPzhFNwg) out there if you need some help.

Just Add <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> an E̲ffect Strip... T̲ext. You can animate it's opacity if needed and change it's size and position. [image: example of adding a Text Strip in the VSE]

Comment: jaja, this was exactly what I wanted. some monts ago, thanks Samoth!

Comment: And now with [font selection](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/15/blender-developers-meeting-notes-14-january-2019/) :-) yeah